# How to see pending AJAX requests with Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

A feature I like about Firebug in Firefox is that it shows AJAX requests in progress (before they finish). Chrome, however, won't show a request until it completes. Is there a way to see pending (in progress) network requests with Chrome developer tools? I want to identify as soon as possible any AJAX requests that are causing delays. In some scenarios a bad request may take 15 or 30 seconds and it does not make sense to wait that long to know what is going on.

Please note: I can see the network requests. My question *is not* how to see network requests.

Edit: I must correct my statement above that Chrome won't show pending requests. It does show them. The specific problem is that *pending* ajax requests do not show in the Network->XHR panel; they only show there when they are finished. The Network->All panel does show the pending XHR requests.

Comment: I just tested cause I found it strange, and the `Network` tab in my chrome developer tools shows my request as soon as it is sent, not waiting for the response. Are you sure you don't have a javascript problem in chrome only causing the request not to be sent at all in that browser ?

Comment: I don't believe so. What is the slowest ajax request you are looking at? (Maybe it's too quick for you to see whether it is in progress or finished) Is there any indication that the request has started versus when it has completed? I assume that if a request has started it shouldn't show a total time in the Time column or the total time will change once it finishes. I see no change in the total time so I assume it is being shown after it finishes. I am using Chrome 33.0.1750.152 (latest).

Comment: Well maybe you're debugging it bad, but I tested it when debugging my server-side code, so I was 100% sure it didn't respond as it was stuck on a breakpoint in my server-side code... I did see the request in chrome, with an empty `response` tab and a "pending" indication in the `time` column . As soon as I released my code for execution, the `response`tab got filled aswell as the time elapsed, corresponding to the time I hold the process.

Comment: Thanks. I just did that same exercise. The request won't show in the Network->XHR tab when pending. I now noticed that it shows in the Network->ALL tab as pending however. Once it finishes then it also shows in the Network->XHR tab. Are you able to reproduce this? My javascript code uses jQuery's $.getJSON function. It seems the Chrome developer tools are not showing the request as XHR until it finishes which seems wrong.

Comment: Indeed, I just very logically reproduced the same behaviour. I'm not able to tell if that's a bug or a feature though. But it would indeed be quite logic to have it identified as XHR from the time it is initiated as it is exactly how it is initiated. Well at least you know where to find it while it is pending ;-)

Comment: Any updates on this? I just realized I can't see pending requests either.

Edit: nevermind, I can't read. I found it.

Comment: Yeah it seems as though Chrome cant decide to show me the progress. Sometimes it does, then I restart and it doesnt. If anyone has a suggestion, fire away.

Answer (score 30):

Press the filter button, and type `status-code:0`:

[image: pic]

Looks like it also includes a few other things like data urls, but it should be good enough.

**Update 6/23/2015**: the syntax is now "status-code:0", not "StatusCode:0".

Comment: I think you meant `status-code:0` <-- which will show you requests that have a status code of `0`. Which I think is wrong. Don't you mean `status-code:200`? This also changed nothing for me in Chrome.

Comment: You're right, it is status-code now. They must have changed the syntax. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Link to the documentation?

Comment: Is there any way to check this through Javascript?

Comment: First impression is this is a partial answer as it is showing jpg and any other request not just XHR.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of canceled requests? Those also show up when using `status-code:0`

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Network > Other` tab to see pending requests.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the inspect>network will show the get/post requests, but you might have to hit the red record button first.

Comment: Thanks but I think you misunderstood my question. The network panel is showing all the requests, that is not the problem.